# Number of ways to partition numbers with preservation of the ordinal characteristics.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a set of integers $M = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

How many ways are there to partition M into $k<n$ subsets so that the following condition is true:
$\forall \;x \in M_i\, , y \in M_j \, , i < j: x < y $ ?

Example:
$M = \{1,2,3\}$, $k = 2$
One valid parition would be
$M_1 = \{1\}$ , $M_2= \{2,3\}$. Another partition would be  $M_1 = \{1, 2\}$ , $M_2= \{3\}$

Is there a relation to the Stirling numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler. Suppose $n=8, k = 4$

You need to place $4-1$ dividers in the $8-1$ gaps between numbers as shown below.

$1\cdot 2\; |\; 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\; |\; 6\cdot 7\; |\; 8$

Thus number of such subsets $= \binom73,\; in \;general,\; \binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Comment: True. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome !